# Why request get blocked by CORS when 'http' is not included?

Tags: http, cors, xmlhttprequest

I was struggling with requesting data from an endpoint. At first, I attempted to fetch some data at localhost:8000/api/jobs' but it threw the error bellow:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/api/jobs' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.
```

However, when I included 'http://' after localhost it worked just fine. Why does it behave like this?

as said before, the matter was solved by including 'http://'. I just want to know why is it needed.